# How do I detect if a particular firebase storage path data has changed

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-storage

firebase database has a function where I can retrieve data again when something changed in the path

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + Auth.uid + '/profileImg').on('value', function(snapshot) { //do things when the data changed});
```

I was wondering if anyone know if firebase storage does the same thing? For example if I upload another profile pic, how can I can retrieve that imageUrl?

I understand I can retrieve it in the way below, but since I want to detect changes in another controller that is not in the same controller as the upload place, this method would not work.

```
                        uploadTask.on('state_changed', function (snapshot) {
                        // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
                        // See below for more detail
                    }, function (error) {
                        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                    }, function () {
                        $scope.userProfile = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
                    });
                }, function (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                });
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase Storage has no built-in capability to proactively alert clients when a file is changed.

This is something you can easily build by combining Firebase Storage with the Firebase Realtime Database. Keep the downloadURL of your file in the database and add a `lastModified` timestamp:

```
images
  $imageid
    downloadUrl: "https://downloadUrl"
    lastModified: 123873278327
```

Whenever you upload/update an image in Firebase Storage, update the downloadUrl/timestamp in the database:

```
uploadTask.on('state_changed', function (snapshot) {
    // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
    // See below for more detail
}, function (error) {
    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
}, function () {
    $scope.userProfile = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
    databaseRef.child('images').child(imageId).set({
        downloadUrl: uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL,
        lastModified: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
    })
});
```

Now you can know when an image has been modified, by listening to the database location for that image:

```
databaseRef.child('images').child(imageId).on('value', function(snapshot) {
  // take the downloadUrl from the snapshot and update the UI
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  Frank, I will give this a try, but I think it will work. Also, just wondering if you know this, does the downloadURL changes with time/location even if the actual content doesn't change? So right now, I am getting a new downloadURL each time I need instead of saving it in the database, should I just save it in the database?

Comment: And also I believe that timestamp was supported by firebase2. Here is the code for firebase3 firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

Comment: Fixed the code. Thanks for that. I keep forgetting that ServerValue.TIMESTAMP moved.

Comment: Do you mind also answer my other questions? Here is the link. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404273/does-firebase3-storage-url-changes-with-time-or-location