# Does firebase3 storage url changes with time or location

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I was wondering if I can save the url that I get from storage in to my database and retrieve the link every time I want the image? Right now, I am calling the following function each time I need to get an image and it is slow. I am just afraid that the link might change depending on where the user is and time?

```
           storage.ref(thisEvent.eventImgInReference).getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {                         
                            //here I just add the image url
                            thisEvent.eventImgLink=url;
                            //
                            $scope.$apply();
                        }).catch(function (error) {
           });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download URLs only change if you revoke the download token in the Firebase Console, so it's totally fine if you store them in your database.