# Retrieve Images from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got to retrieve the images uploaded to the Firebase Storage into an app using android studio to make the app. This is basically like a realtime notice board for the app and the images uploaded into firebase storage should automatically be refreshed into the app. I am new to Firebase and this was assigned to me. Can anyone please guide me through?

I've already tried creating Model class and ViewHolder class and tried recycler view but it doesn't respond. The app always force closes. The format in which images are stored is listed.

Edit (Code using Recycler View)
activity_notices.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Notices"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview">
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Model.java

```
package com.example.finalapkx;

public class Model {

    String title,image,description;
    public Model() {}

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="3dp"
    app:contentPadding="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rTitleTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/loading"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rDescriptionTv"
            android:text="This will be description of the Notice"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

ViewHolder.java

```
package com.example.finalapkx;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);


        mView = itemView;
    }
    public void setDetails(Context ctx,String title,String description, String image){
        TextView mTitleTv = mView.findViewById(R.id.rTitleTv);
        TextView mDetailTv = mView.findViewById(R.id.rDescriptionTv);
        ImageView mImageIv = mView.findViewById(R.id.rImageView);
        mTitleTv.setText(title);
        mDetailTv.setText(description);
        Picasso.get().load(image).into(mImageIv);
    }
}
```

Notices.java

```
package com.example.finalapkx;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;
import com.firebase.client.core.Context;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


public class Notices extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView mrecyclerView;
FirebaseDatabase mfirebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference mRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notices);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Notices List");
        mrecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mrecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mfirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mRef = mfirebaseDatabase.getReference("images");


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(Model.class,R.layout.row,ViewHolder.class,mRef) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Model model, int i) {
                        viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(),model.getTitle(),model.getDescription(),model.getImage());

                    }
                };
           mrecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
}
```

Logcat error

```
2019-08-02 10:56:21.013 7174-7174/com.example.finalapkx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.finalapkx, PID: 7174
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.finalapkx/com.example.finalapkx.Notices}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.finalapkx.Notices.onCreate(Notices.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2019-08-02 10:56:21.030 7174-7174/com.example.finalapkx I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7174 SIG: 9
```

Androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.finalapkx">
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:name=".AC4"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".AC3" />
        <activity android:name=".AC2" />
        <activity android:name=".AC1" />
        <activity android:name=".pdfyearone" />

        <activity android:name=".Visit" />
        <activity android:name=".Administration" />
        <activity android:name=".Leadership" />
        <activity android:name=".VisMis" />
        <activity android:name=".ACCA" />
        <activity android:name=".Genesis" />
        <activity android:name=".Results" />
        <activity android:name=".PHARMA3" />
        <activity android:name=".MECH3" />
        <activity android:name=".IT3" />
        <activity android:name=".EEE3" />
        <activity android:name=".ECE3" />
        <activity android:name=".CSE3" />
        <activity android:name=".CIVIL3" />
        <activity android:name=".CHEMICAL3" />
        <activity android:name=".Year3" />
        <activity android:name=".CHEMICAL2" />
        <activity android:name=".CIVIL2" />
        <activity android:name=".MECH2" />
        <activity android:name=".PHARMA2" />
        <activity android:name=".IT2" />
        <activity android:name=".EEE2" />
        <activity android:name=".ECE2" />
        <activity android:name=".CSE2" />
        <activity android:name=".CHEMICAL" />
        <activity android:name=".CIVIL" />
        <activity android:name=".MECH" />
        <activity android:name=".PHARMA" />
        <activity android:name=".IT" />
        <activity android:name=".EEE" />
        <activity android:name=".ECE" />
        <activity android:name=".CSE" />
        <activity android:name=".Year4" />
        <activity android:name=".Year2" />
        <activity android:name=".Year1" />
        <activity android:name=".ExamPrep" />
        <activity android:name=".About" />
        <activity android:name=".Notices" />
        <activity android:name=".Events" />
        <activity android:name=".Calendar" />
        <activity android:name=".Attendance" />
        <activity android:name=".Launch" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: provide some code/ screenshots?

Comment: If the app crashes, there's going to be an error message written to logcat. Please find it, and edit your question to include the exact message and stack trace.

Comment: I think this is the solution for your question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387479/how-do-i-detect-if-a-particular-firebase-storage-path-data-has-changed

Comment: the problem come from action bar, see your `AndroidManifet.xml`